# JLabel setText() method is said to be threadsafe, but does it ensure visibility

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, visibility, volatile

looking into the source code of JLabel I have a concern of visibility for the text field.
I extracted the essential part to set the text field and retrieve oldValue.
To my opinion if the String text field is not declared volatile, visibility is in danger as the firePropertyChange might not see the oldValue retrieved from the text field saved by another thread before.
Am I right, or do I miss out something? 
Please note this is not to discuss about SwingUtility.

```
public class JLabel extends JComponent implements SwingConstants, Accessible {
    ...

    private String text = "";         // "" rather than null, for BeanBox

    ...

    public void setText(String text) {

        String oldAccessibleName = null;
        if (accessibleContext != null) {
            oldAccessibleName = accessibleContext.getAccessibleName();
        }

        String oldValue = this.text;
        this.text = text;
        firePropertyChange("text", oldValue, text);

    ...
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `Please note this is not to discuss about SwingUtility.`, right, sure I agreed, for better help sooner post an  [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) short, runnable, compilable, just about `JFrame` with one `JLabel` only

Comment: _JLabel setText() method is said to be threadsafe_ who/what says such nonsense?

Comment: Oh sorry JTextPane seems to have a threadsafe setText() method, however it does not have this text field like the JLabel looking up. But in general the code snippet above does not ensure visibility across several threads, right? Just this would answer my question.

Comment: I do not see anything in the JDK7 documentation that suggests that JTextPane#setText is thread safe

Comment: Well, JTextPane inherits setText from JEditorPane. For JDK6, the documentations says it is thread safe. For JDK 7 it says it's not.

Answer (score 5):

Based on what you've written, no, that would not ensure visibility (although I don't see how declaring anything volatile will help).  In [this bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4765383) it is stated that a number of methods in the JDK 6 documentation falsely declare they are thread safe (see bottom of page), `JEditorPane.setText` is one of them (hence the reason that statement is not in the JDK 7 documentation).